# any type function parameter

Tags: visual-c++

I have function body:

```
 cout<<value;
```

I would like to make function that could have any type parameter named `value` to use possibility to pass many types parameter to `cout`.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: so you want the `cout` to work with any type

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much describing templates.

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(const T &value)
{
   std::cout << value;
}
```

If instead you're asking "I have an type `T` that I want to be able to serialize with `std::cout`", you need to overload `operator <<` within your class.

```
class MyType
{
   int x;

   friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &stream, const MyType &value)
   {
      return std::cout << value.x;
   }
};
```